# How do I discover which function is called when I press a button?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck modifying someone else's source code, and unfortunately it's very strongly NOT documented.

I'm trying to figure out which function is called when I press a button as part of an effort to trace the current bug to it's source, and I"m having no luck.  From what I can tell, the function is dynamically added to the button after it's generated.  As a result, there's no onlick="" for me to examine, and I can't find anything else in my debug panel that helps.

While I prefer Chrome, I'm more than willing to boot up in a different browser if I have to.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible, but I'll think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, type the following in your URL bar after the page has been fully loaded (don't forget to change the button class):

```
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("ButtonClass"); alert(b[0].onclick);
```

or you can try (make the appropriate changes for the correct button id):

```
var b = document.getElementById("ButtonID"); alert(b.onclick);
```

This should alert the function name/code snippet in a message box.

After having the function name or the code snippet you just gotta perform a seach through the .js files for the snippet/function name.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open page with your browser's JavaScript debugger open
2. Click "Break all" or equivalent
3. Click button you wish to investigate (may require some finesse if mouseovering page elements causes events to be fired.  If timeouts or intervals occur in the page, they may get in the way, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the buttons markup and look at its class / id. Use that class or id and search the JavaScript, it's quite likely that the previous developer has done something like

```
document.getElementById('someId').onclick = someFunction...;
```

or

`document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);`

Comment: Yeah, I eventually managed to trace it to the latter.  Looks like they used some kind of pre-created factory code to attach functions to the buttons in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trace variable to each function. Use console.log() to view the trace results.

Like so:

```
function blah(trace) {
    console.log('blah called from: '+trace);
}
```

(to view the results, you have to open the developer console)